# Restlet Reference scheme reverts to http when using https

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I have a simple Restlet application using the embedded org.restlet.Server in restlet-jse-2.2.3 which worked fine with HTTP. Following the Restlet book, I converted it to use HTTPS instead. However, within my ServerResource instances, getReference() is returning References using the HTTP scheme even though the application is only accessed vi HTTPS. Even the org.restlet.routing.Redirector is confused, taking a relative target and returning a URI with the http schema.

Here's the gist of my main():

```
Component component = new Component();
Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTPS, 8081);
Series<Parameter> parameters = server.getContext().getParameters();
parameters.add("keystorePath", ...);
parameters.add("keystorePassword", ...);
parameters.add("keystoreType", ...);
parameters.add("keyPassword", ...);
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(new MyApplication());
component.start();
```

And in MyApplication.createInboundRoot()

```
Router router = new Router(getContext());
router.attach("/", new Redirector(getContext(), "/servers",
                                  Redirector.MODE_CLIENT_FOUND));
router.attach(...);
...
```

All my various attached ServerResource instances work fine when addressed as `https://my.host:MYPORT/...`, but the Reference instances returned by their getReference() method is always of the form `http://my.host:MYPORT/...` forcing me to override the scheme to https to generate
relative links, and hitting `https://my.host:MYPORT/` returns a redirect to `http://my.host:MYPORT/servers`, which of course then fails.

What am I missing that is causing the incoming https scheme in the URIs to be rewritten to http?

Comment: I did some more digging on this. I do not claim a deep understanding of the Restlet implementation, but it appears to me that the problem is that the org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpsServerHelper.confidential flag is not being set to true and that similarly when an org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpExchangeCall instance is created by the HttpsServerHelper, its confidential flag is also not being set. This results in creating the org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpRequest instance with both the resourceRef and originalRef references initialized with the http schema instead of https.

Comment: Thanks very such for investigating more the problem! According to that you described, it seems to be a bug in the framework itself... It would be great if you could open an issue in the github project (https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues). Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks, just did: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/998

Comment: Thanks a lot for reporting this issue. The fix is now available in the 2.3 and 3.0 branches.